Will minidlna create a DLNA sink
I have a DLNA renderer on my network, and an AlmaLinux 9 server (in text mode) where I would like to play sound.
I want to send the sounds from my AlmaLinux 9 server to the DLNA renderer, but I have no sound device (sink) on my server.  I have pipewire installed, and pipewire-pulseaudio.  I just can't figure out how to create the sink.  My google searches keep pointing my to minidlna - but will minidlna create the sink (for local sounds to be sent to)?  I don't want a dlna server (playing music files), just a virtual sound device that all programs can send audio to.
